# Create DTO classes from POCO classes C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, dto

I'm having some troubles of defining how should the **DTO** classes for my **POCO** classes look. I'm using Entity Framework 6.

Here is the example of one **POCO** class:

```
public class Measurement()
{
    public long MeasurementID;
    public long Value;
    public DateTime Timestamp;
    public long? ApplicationID;
    public long? DeviceID;
    public long? SensorID;  
}
```

Should I define **DTO** for this class in the same manner as the **POCO** classes, where **DTO** object will have exactly same attributes?

Or should there be actual values, for example, ***DeviceName*** instead of ***DeviceID*** in this case?

Basic idea is:

Client does some measurement, packs it into object that'll have same properties as Measurement **POCO** class, just instead of ID's there will be real property values. (***DeviceName*** for example etc.) So, how should be **DTO** defined at server's side? ID properties are meaningful to server, but real values are meaningful to client. I'm a bit confused of how should the mapping between **DTO** and **POCO** look and what in general to put in DTO.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: POCO could be anything. A DTO can be a POCO depending on the repository framework. I think you really want to figure out how to handle the DTO and the Business Object (BO), not DTO and POCO. Also most these will also have properties, not public fields.

Comment: Your code is an example of what not to do; [Do not use instance fields that are public](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta31s3bc(v=vs.71).aspx)..

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. That measurement class is generated by EntityFramework, I used Code First from Database approach, with some modifications on annotations above fields (I've removed them). What bugs me most is should I create DTO object containing those ID fields, or should have other values (for example DeviceName instead of DeviceID). That is my main concern. If you have any project examples on best practices on how to create DTOs, that would be of great help.

Comment: DTO's should just match what is needed. If you're using a DTO for a database, put in what is needed to insert and/or retrieve. If you're using a DTO to transfer data across the wire, only send what is required. There most likely should not be any logic. Just put what you need. I am almost thinking you are getting DTO confused with the ViewModel. DTO's should have nothing to do with the client at least visibly to the user. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture